# Matching agents to category in anylogic/airport model

Tags: agent, anylogic

I'm simulating airport passenger flow on anylogic. and i have 2 category of passengers(Business and economy).
arriving at security control blocks.i have 6 scanners for economy and 2 for business and i want that Each type of passenger go to its appropriate scanner depending to its category (business passenger to business scanners and eco passenger to eco scaners),

My agents are scanners, i named the agent "securityControl_PIF", this agent have a simple wating area+queue+service from pedestrain library.
I created for each category, business or economy, a collection for waiting area, for services , for queues shapes, and for target lines. 
i puted on the main startup, the method ADD.securityControl_PIF(...) 
`/*values of securityControl_PIF parameters***********************************/
for (int i = 0; i<6; i++) { 
add_securityControl_PIF(queueBeforePIFShapesEco.get(i),waitbeforePifEco,stopLinesBeforePIFEco.get(i),max(0,(securityControlTimeMean_PIF - 10)), securityControlTimeMean_PIF, securityControlTimeMean_PIF+10, detectorPassedProba, securityControlPIFTimeStat,true);}
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
add_securityControl_PIF(queueBeforePIFShapesBus.get(i),waitbeforePifBus,stopLinesBeforePIFBus.get(i),max(0,(securityControlTimeMean_PIF - 10)), securityControlTimeMean_PIF, securityControlTimeMean_PIF+10, detectorPassedProba, securityControlPIFTimeStat,false);}`
i hope that it's clear, i couldn't attach an image to present the composent of my agent.
thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your question feels so confusing... I don't think you will ever get an answer unless you fix its grammar and narration. I think maybe a native english speaking friend can help you out on how to formulate this question properly and have more chances of getting help

Comment: thanks Felipe, i improved the post.